# Dimension of subspace spanned by group orbit

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, group-actions

Consider the space $\mathbb{F}_2^n$, and a group $G$ acting on this space. I can then pick a point $x \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$, and obtain an orbit $G \cdot x = \{gx : g \in G\}$.

It is then possible to verify that $\dim(G\cdot x) = \dim(G) - \dim(G_x)$, with $G_x$ the stabilizers of $x$.

However, I would like to be able to quantify the dimension of $\mathbb{F}_2^n[G\cdot x]$ instead, i.e. the *subspace* generated by $G \cdot x$. Is there a general formalism that tackles this question?

Comment: What is $\text{dim}(G)$?

Comment: The algebraic dimension of $G$ : https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Dimension_of_an_algebraic_group

Comment: This is the dimension of the subrepresentation spanned by $x$. For general $x$ you can figure it out from knowing the decomposition of the ambient space into irreps, but for particular $x$, it can vary.

Comment: @JakeLevinson oh right, makes sense, the space splits as $\mathbb{F}_2^n = W_1 \oplus W_2 \oplus ...$. So if $x \in W_2$, then the dimension of the subspace generated is simply that of $W_2$. Am I getting this right?

Comment: @loplo yes more or less - the space may not split as a direct sum since Maschke’s theorem doesn’t hold. In characteristic zero the statement would be that if $V$ splits into isotypic components as $\oplus V_i^{k_i}$, then a general $x$ will generate a direct sum consisting of one copy of each $V_i$ on which $x$ has a nonzero part.